# Why isn't export working from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, export

Why isn't exporting a variable working in the following case:

In the following example I export the PARAM variable and set the sleep to 1000 second in order to run the script as process on the background.

```
#!/bin/bash

export PARAM="I AM A REAL VALUE"

sleep 1000
```

so I execute the script as process as the following:

```
 /tmp/example.bash &
```

Now script runs as a process (I checked it with `ps -ef`) and from the Linux console I want to print the `$PARAM` as the following

```
 echo $PARAM
```

but no value from PARAM variable.

Why? The `export` from the script isn’t exporting the value when the script process is running.

Comment: because your script spawns a new child shell and then you go back to parent shell and check for variable.

Comment: You are running the script under subshell. subshell cannot change parent shell environment (not without any hack at least.) You need to [source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107969/what-is-the-difference-between-source-x-x-and-x-in-bash) it.

Comment: so what is the way to print the vars from the console ? or from other script

Comment: Use the `.` command or (in Bash or C shells) the `source` command to read the file.  OTOH, you probably don't want to wait over 15 minutes to see the results; lose the `sleep 1000`.

Comment: hi please write your answer , so I will can vote for your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `/tmp/example.bash &`, you set the environment in the sub-shell, but that does not affect the parent shell that ran it.

You need to (a) remove the `sleep 1000` and (b) use the `.` command or (in Bash or a C shell) the `source` command to read the file as part of the current process:

```
sed -i.bak '/sleep/d' /tmp/example.bash  # GNU or BSD sed
. /tmp/example.bash
echo $PARAM
```

Comment: you shuld write this . ./tmp/example.bash ( you forget the "." )

Comment: There isn't a `.` in front of `/tmp/example.bash` in the question, so it is not I who forgot the leading dot.  But fixing a file name to match your local requirements is hardly rocket science; it is pretty much assumed in any SO answer where files are used — reworking the names to meet the actual location names is necessary.